# .NET Core HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long

Tags: .net, .net-core, http-error

I have 3 .NET Core services (just regular console applications) running and doing HTTP requests to one of my api controllers every 30s, but after a while I get this error `HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long.`

I have added a lot of logs to see whats in the header, payload etc, and the only headers that are in the request (same for all 3 services). The request message looks like this:

```
09:38:33.8301756 | TRACE | RequestMessage is: Method: GET, RequestUri: 'https://xxxx.xxxx.xx/api/v1/xxxx/xxxx', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers:
{
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
}
```

I have tried adding this to my API controller:

```
services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Limits.MaxRequestHeadersTotalSize = 1024 * 1024;
            });
```

But no diffrerence..

The API controller is running on .NET Core 3.1 and the services with .NET 6

Thanks in advance!

Best regards Max

Comment: Can you use Fiddler to see what traffic is actually on the wire?

Comment: What an amazing tool, it seems like it += application/json, so it gets reallllly long :D Now I know what to fix! Thanks!